# Button to enable multiple display (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, external-display

I'm creating a windows app for windows 8.1 tablet. And I was wondering if it was possible to create a button within the app that will enable me to turn on and off the external display connected to the tablet. Similar to a computer when a projector is connected, a user must press a key in order to show or turn off the display on the projector.

Instead of swiping on the right edge and choosing devices and selecting the multiple display. I want to be able to do this within the app with a press of a single button to enable and disable the multiple display function. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an sample from Windows 8.1 SDK that might guide you through the implementation:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Multiple-Views-Sample-2582fcf3

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to create a second view. I want to create a button that allows me to connect to an external monitor (duplicate the display my tablet is showing)